# Cache in ServiceStack web services

Tags: asp.net, caching, servicestack

I am new to caching and trying to understand how it works in general. Below is code snippet from [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Northwind/ServiceStack.Northwind.ServiceInterface/CachedServices.cs) website.

```
public object Get(CachedCustomers request)
{
    //Manually create the Unified Resource Name "urn:customers".
    return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, "urn:customers", () =>
    {
         //Resolve the service in order to get the customers.
         using (var service = this.ResolveService<CustomersService>())
                return service.Get(new Customers());
     });
}

public object Get(CachedCustomerDetails request)
{
    //Create the Unified Resource Name "urn:customerdetails:{id}".
    var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<CustomerDetails>(request.Id);
    return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, cacheKey, () =>
    {
        using (var service = this.ResolveService<CustomerDetailsService>())
        {
             return service.Get(new CustomerDetails { Id = request.Id });
        }
    });
}
```

My doubts are:

1. I've read that cached data is stored in RAM on same/distributed server. So, how much data can it handle, suppose in first method if customers count is more than 1 million, doesn't it occupy too much memory.
2. In general case, do we apply caching only for GET operations and invalidate if it gets UPDATE'd.
3. Please suggest any tool to check memory consumption of caching.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find the answers to your questions here -https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching

**I've read that cached data is stored in RAM on same/distributed server...**

There are several ways to 'persist' cached data.  Again, see here - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching. 'InMemory' is the option you seem to be questioning. The other options don't have the same impact on RAM.

**In general case, do we apply caching only for GET operations and invalidate if it gets UPDATE'd.**

In ServiceStack you can manually clear/invalidate the cache or have a time based expiration. If you manually clear the cache I would recommend doing so on DELETES and UPDATES. You are free to choose how you manage/invalidate the cache. You just want to avoid having stale data in your cache. As far as 'apply caching' you would return cached data on GET operations, but your system can access cached data just like any other data store. Again, you just need recognize the cache my not have the most recent set of data.